# For which pairs of real numbers $(\alpha,x)$ does the sequence $\sin(\alpha^n\pi x)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory

For which pairs of real numbers $(\alpha,x)$ with $\alpha>1$ does the sequence $\sin(\alpha^n\pi x)$ converge?

As pointed out in a comment on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538942), given an integer value of $\alpha$, the sequence converges for all integer values of $x$. In the short time since that question was posted, I have learned that the premise of the question - that $\sin(\alpha^n\pi x)$ almost never converges to $0$ - is probably wrong.

This makes me very sad.

It also makes me want to know when $\sin(\alpha^n\pi x)$ *does* converge - to $0$ or any other real number.

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/q/448108/72031

Comment: The premise (that $\sin(\alpha^n \pi x)$ almost never converges to $0$) is true (edit: probably true; I still haven't checked the german proof mentioned in the comments of the previous post)